# how to fix jquery error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" for blue-imp gallery in modal Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I used bootstrap 3 and blueimp-gallery in a web html5. My problem is a carousel-gallery dont show images and receive a error in a console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" when i use a blueimp-gallery-carousel in a modal div, but if i enter in a developer tools for chrome, this error disappears, and the images show in carousel-gallery.

The code.

```
<!-- Portfolio Modals -->
<!-- Use the modals below to showcase details about your portfolio projects! -->

<!-- Portfolio Modal 1 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Vinilos</h2>
                            <div id="links">
                                <a href="images/productos/vinilos/02.jpg" title="Banana">1</a>
                                <a href="images/productos/vinilos/03.jpg" title="Apple">2</a>
                                <a href="images/productos/vinilos/04.jpg" title="Orange">3</a>
                                <a href="images/productos/vinilos/05.jpg" title="Banana"></a>
                                <a href="images/productos/vinilos/06.jpg" title="Apple"></a>
                                <a href="images/productos/vinilos/07.jpg" title="Orange"></a>
                            </div>

                            <div id="blueimp-gallery-carousel" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-carousel blueimp-gallery-controls">
                                <div class="slides"></div>
                                <h3 class="title"></h3>
                                <a class="prev">‹</a>
                                <a class="next">›</a>
                                <a class="play-pause"></a>
                                <ol class="indicator"></ol>
                            </div>

                            <p>Vinilos para rotulacion, decorativos, efecto espejo, fibra de carbono, refractivos, hologramas y farolas</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cerrar Producto</button>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and my javascript

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
      event = event || window.event;
      var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
      blueimp.Gallery(links, options);

    };
</script>

<script>
    blueimp.Gallery(
        document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        {
            container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
            carousel: true,
        }
    );
</script>
```

and the link web problem

http://www.colombiawaterprint.com/web/index3.html

How i Solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that your blueimp gallery is initially hidden as it is in a Bootstrap Modal. As such, when you first initialize the gallery it can't find the gallery. I think all you need to do is wait for the Bootstrap modal to be shown and *then* initialize the gallery.

Bootstrap triggers an event that you can listen for for this very purpose - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events - You probably want the `shown.bs.modal` event.

You would use it something like this. (assuming jQuery is loaded)

```
$('#portfolioModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  blueimp.Gallery(
        document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a'),
        {
            container: '#blueimp-gallery-carousel',
            carousel: true,
        }
    );
})
```

Bear in mind this is untested code and may not 'just work'. But hopefully you get the idea. You also may want to do a test to see if you've already initialized the gallery, as it stands this would re-initialize it every time the `shown.bs.modal` event was fired.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your suggestions. I try with your solution, but the gallery dissapear with the method shown.bs.modal. I don't understand what happend.

If use method hide.bs.modal work in a second try to view gallery. 

Thanks for your time.